Access Key Vault secret from Azure Data Factory using RBAC (Role-Based Access Control)
I am setting up a pipeline in an Azure Data Factory and would like to access a secret stored in an Azure Key Vault using RBAC (Role-Based Access Control).
I found this three tutorials which all cover part of what I would like to do: access key vault from web utility, use-azure-key-vault-secrets-pipeline-activities and Does ADF support access AKV secrets with Azure RBAC?
So what I did is the following:

Go to Key Vault - Access control (IAM) and added the DataFactory with the role "Reader"
Added a Web Utility to the pipeline
Configured the following URL: https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/MY-SECRET/UUID?api-version=7.0
Method = GET
Authentication = System Assigned Managed Identity
Resource = https://vault.azure.net

However when I execute the pipeline I get the following error:

"error": {
"code": "Unauthorized",
"message": "AKV10000: Request is missing a Bearer or PoP token."
}

Unfortunately I could not find a solution yet. The tutorials do not mention any further steps to get a token. Do I really need one and if so - how do I get it?

this might help - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-use-azure-key-vault-secrets-pipeline-activities
